# Eclipse messing with Holo Theme

Tags: android, android-theme

In my Eclipse I have all the themes working properly but not the Holo one (see picture)

Why? What's happened and which files should I fix?

[image: Eclipse Fail]

Comment: Are you updated to the latest ADT plugin version? If not, update it.

Comment: No updates were found. My version is the last